# how to remove tinymce interface (diplay only innerhtml) for printing

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce

I have a page with multiple textareas, for which I will be using tinymce. I would like, however, for the tinymce interface (all buttons and menues) to not display on print (ctrl + p.) I just want the content to display.  using chrome and tinymce Version: 4.6.4-61.
Is this best done with css?

Comment: It can be done with css, look into [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp), and targeting the `print` media. I've had the best results by first copying all the content I actually want to print to a single div with some js, while hiding the rest with css.

Comment: I got there, but not very savy with the js so this is why I ask.  so I use @media print, and have a class with 'display: none'  but how do I refer to the editor?? How do I seperate the editor from the html??  an example would be a big help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp) you can style specifically for printed content.

The General approach to this is to have one div containing all the content you want to print, all other elements will be set to `display:none` and are therefor hidden.

```
@media print {
  /* hide everything */
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  /* show everything in the div you want to print */
  #content-to-print,
  #content-to-print * {
    visibility: visible;
  }
  #content-to-print {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

How and when you provide content to the print div is outside the scope of this question. Listening for <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> can be quite a hassle. IMHO the easiest way is to keep a shadow copy of the print content at all times. you can hide the copy with  a `@media screen` rule.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gMVSE/99/) for a concrete example